# Filming with projector

Tags: video, camera, projector

I want to make an educational video. I am using a camera (Canon 250d), a projector, and some lights.

The problem is that when I brighten the room or make light on the speaker, the text on the projector gets difficult to read.

What can I change with my camera settings or the light setup to change this. So the room is bright and the text on the projector is easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky to solve with a single camera shot  - your projector probably needs a darkened room to get decent contrast.  You need to balance the exposure as best you can between the speaker and the image.

I would suggest that if you're making a video with the speaker visible, you probably want to prioritise being able to see the speaker more than the projection image (otherwise why bother filming them?).

If you light the presenter separately from the projector and at a distance from the screen so the light doesn't spill onto it, you will have a better chance at getting them both visible.

But another way to do it would be to just film the speaker with your camera, and take a copy of the presentation (either during the presentation or afterwards), and edit it into the video afterwards at appropriate points.

This gives you the best of both worlds, and doesn't require a second camera, but does require more post-production editing time.

The final suggestion is that sound is as important as pictures in these videos.  You can get away with a slightly dodgy shot of a speaker if their sound is good.  But if the sound is echoey and indistinct, few people will persevere with a long lecture.

Record the speaker with a clip mic attached to a phone - even a pair of apple wired headphones work ok for this.  Clip it as close to the top of their shirt as you can without rubbing against them.  Plug it into a spare phone and record it as a voice memo.  Sync the audio and video up later when you add the presentation images.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the brightness and contrast of the picture on the projector. And it’s better to play with the light - direct only at yourself, not at the screen.